# Wordpress Center photo in Fast Gallery without cuts

Tags: css, wordpress

I have on my site Fast Gallery on popup in essential grid and i have one small problem. When i open portfolio item, there is fast gallery Fotorama slider and photos are cut off a little. I tried i think everything but i don't know how to fix that. Can someone help?
Here is my site: http://nakme.naszastrona.eu/
Open first portfolio item.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in you css:

```
   .fotorama__stage {
    height: 371px !important;
    width: 630px !important;
}
```

That should work. :)

Comment: When i do that, the up part of photo is cut off. :/

Comment: Cut off? Are you sure. Please do so, and I will check your website. Let me know here when you do.

Comment: I made your changes, check it out.

Comment: Everything seems fine now, could you please post your screenshot?

Comment: here are my screenshots. In both screens you can see that images are cut off [link]http://imgur.com/a/0LAMm

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome but on firefox it looks the same

Comment: Please see edited code. I have tested on 4 browsers and it's working fine. You need to c/p it into this file: http://nakme.naszastrona.eu/wp-content/plugins/fastgallery/css/fotorama.css